# Plots are clipped randomly (almost)

Tags: plotting

I am experiencing a strange behavior in plotting a lot of functions. Basically, they are clipped within an horizontal range. Let try to run this code by varying nmax, it could be a problem of my specific configuration(?). I know that is not a problem about Manipulate since I can reproduce the same behavior with a static plot. Rather it seems to be a problem related to point numbers, indeed if you try to sharpen the gaussians the problem appears.

```
nmax = 5;
Manipulate[
DynamicModule[{rr = r[[1 ;; n]], ss = s[[1 ;; n]], 
  ww = w[[1 ;; n]]},
  Show[
    Plot[Table[
      PDF[NormalDistribution[rr[[i]], ss[[i]]], x], {i, 1, n}], {x, 0, 
    5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1.4}}, Frame -> True]
 ]
 ],
{{r, RandomReal[{0, 3}, nmax]}, ControlType -> None},
{{s, RandomReal[{0.01, 1}, nmax]}, ControlType -> None},
{{w, RandomReal[{0, 1}, nmax]}, ControlType -> None},
{{n, 1}, 1, nmax, 1},
Dynamic[
Grid[
Table[With[{i = i},
 {Row[{Slider[Dynamic[r[[i]]], {0, 5, 0.1}], Dynamic[r[[i]]]}], 
  Row[{Slider[Dynamic[s[[i]]], {0.01, 1, 0.1}], 
    Dynamic[s[[i]]]}]}
], {i, n}]
]
],
ControlPlacement -> Left
]
```

What do you think about?

Thank you very much

F

Comment: Why not post the (probably simpler) code for the static image?

Comment: Because it would not be simpler than this, since it involves kernel density estimation computation, a histogram, the pdf reconstruction and its "manual" reconstruction. The code above reproduces the same effect/problem but with less code... and the solution is to give the right option in Plot[] (I guess)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean is clipped. Can you show with an image? I run your code, and nothing strange appears to me. Some of the graphs go outside the PlotRange that is explicitly given, but that is not surprising.

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem you are seeing:-

[image]

In your code `Show` is actually doing nothing, since `Plot` is plotting all the tabled functions (and that's where the problem is occurring).  The problem is fixed by by rearranging `Plot` and `Table` so that *plots* are tabled, then shown with `Show`. I.e.

```
nmax = 5;
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{rr = r[[1 ;; n]], ss = s[[1 ;; n]], ww = w[[1 ;; n]]},
  Show[Table[Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[rr[[i]],
       ss[[i]]], x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1.4}}, Frame -> True],
    {i, 1, n}]]],
 {{r, RandomReal[{0, 3}, nmax]}, ControlType -> None},
 {{s, RandomReal[{0.01, 1}, nmax]}, ControlType -> None},
 {{w, RandomReal[{0, 1}, nmax]}, ControlType -> None}, {{n, 1}, 1, nmax, 1},
 Dynamic[Grid[Table[With[{i = i},
     {Row[{Slider[Dynamic[r[[i]]], {0, 5, 0.1}], Dynamic[r[[i]]]}],
      Row[{Slider[Dynamic[s[[i]]], {0.01, 1, 0.1}], 
        Dynamic[s[[i]]]}]}], {i, n}]]],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]